# Difference between equal, deep equal, and strict equal

Tags: javascript, node.js

Looking at [Node.js documentation on the `assert` module](http://nodejs.org/api/assert.html), I see functions like `assert.equal`, `assert.strictEqual` and `assert.deepEqual`.

What exactly is the difference between equal, deep equal, and strict equal?

Comment: The documentation says it all.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer to be fair, the page does not define "deep equal."

Comment: Just so you know, deep in the OO context means somethin like "the object and all its properties, all those properties' properties and so on." Aw, you get the picture.

Comment: looked at that page in 2017 and got here:)

Comment: There is a good explanation and example about Shallow and Deep comparison here: https://blog.webnersolutions.com/java-shallow-and-deep-comparison-of-objects

Comment: @TiagoBértolo The question is really badly researched though. The linked documentation clearly spells out in detail what all of the equalities mean. So what exactly is left unclear?

Comment: What is left unclear? Not the question, it is very easy to understand.

The answer however is not there after 9 years.  Seems to be a lot less clear.

Comment: @TiagoBértolo No answer was posted because the question was closed 9 years for good. But the answer is trivial, it's in the documentation that is linked from the question!

Answer (score 11):

As others have stated, the documentation does say what the difference is, but maybe it is not as easy to see.

assert.equal works the same as using a double equals in JavaScript:

```
assert.equal(50, 50);       //true
assert.equal(50, "50");     //true
assert.equal(1, true);      //true
assert.equal(50, 70);       //false
assert.equal({n:1}, {n:1}); //false
```

This means that you get value checking, and JavaScripts fancy type conversions kick in.

assert.strictEqual works just like the triple equals in JavaScript:

```
assert.strictEqual(50, 50);   //true
assert.strictEqual(50, "50"); //false
assert.strictEqual(1, true);  //false
assert.strictEqual(50, 70);   //false
assert.equal({n:1}, {n:1});   //false
```

This means that you get strict comparison checking both value and type.

Both methods check complex objects by reference, not value. That is where deepEquals comes in. deepEquals check objects and their properties for value equality:

```
assert.deepEqual({n:1}, {n:1});    //true
assert.deepEqual({n:1}, {n:true}); //true
assert.deepEqual({n:1}, {n:"1"});  //true
```

deepEquals does a == comparison of type and value for nested properties and child objects of complex objects.

Then you have deepStrictEqual which is just like deepEqual, except that it adds the strict checking of type and value:

```
assert.deepStrictEqual({n:1}, {n:1});    //true
assert.deepStrictEqual({n:1}, {n:true}); //false
assert.deepStrictEqual({n:1}, {n:"1"});  //false
```

So equal and strictEqual test equality of value, and strict adds type, deepEqual and deepStrictEqual check for two objects contain the same properties and values.

W3C Schools have some nice, simple documentation on these topics:
[assert.equal](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_assert_equal.asp)
[assert.strictEqual](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_assert_strictequal.asp)
[assert.deepEqual](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_assert_deepequal.asp)
[assert.deepStrictEqual](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_assert_deepstrictequal.asp)